# How to apply JQuery DataTables to Gridview for large data(>1000) in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I'm applying Jquery DataTables to gridview and it is working fine but for only less than 1000 rows and for large data, first gridview will load then Jquery Datatables will apply, during jquery datatables rendering page become unresponsive and looks ugly.

How I can apply Jquery datatables to Gridview which has large data.

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvDetails" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered  display compact">
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#8b6f4e" ForeColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City" DataField="City" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="State" DataField="State" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Country" DataField="Country" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="BankAc" DataField="BankAc" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Aadhar" DataField="Aadhar" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PhoneNo" DataField="PhoneNo" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmailID" DataField="EmailID" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm applying Jquery Datatable to gridvie like below

```
function bindDataTable() {
        table = $('#<%= gvDetails.ClientID%>').prepend($("<thead></thead>")
          .append($("#<%= gvDetails.ClientID%>").find("tr:first")))
     .DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            stateSave: true
        })
    }
```

is there any other way to apply?

> Note: JQuery DataTables should render fast for large data without
> waiting for Gridview to load first.

Please help if anybody already did this!!

Comment: First you should use repeater rather than gridview which is fast. [These question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193930/using-jquery-datatable-for-server-side-processing-with-paging-filtering-and-sea) could help you.

Comment: So the idea is to fetch only first page data and letter use jquery to load other data. This is bit tricky but refer the link in the attached link.

Answer (score 0):

How long is it taking for the GridView to load the data? It might be better to Ajax load it, or load it per page (called "server-side processing" in DataTables). Please [see the FAQ](//datatables.net/faqs/#speed).

Comment: it is taking long time near 0-2 minus for 30k rows.

Comment: Without DataTables? I'd suggest looking at the server-side processing mode then. It will just get the data to show on each individual page of the DataTable which should be much faster. See the FAQs I linked to for more details.

Comment: no, with datatables gridview load data first and then jquery datatbales will render to gridview.

Comment: Happy to take a look at a test case showing the issue.